# Ejs include with routed url

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

The files `header.ejs`,`menu.ejs`,`footer.ejs` are in `views/layouts/basic/`.

I want to include these files in the `views/index.ejs`.

So, I tried:

```
<% include ./layouts/basic/header.ejs %>
```

It works well. But A lot of view files were created, and the relative paths were all different.

So, in `app.js`:

```
app.use('/layout', express.static(__dirname + '/views/basic/layouts'));
```

and `index.ejs`:

```
<% include /layout/header.ejs %>
```

but it doesn't work. It occurs

```
 ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/layout/header.ejs'
```

However, `header.ejs` is downloaded when you access the browser with 'http://localhost:3000/layout/header.ejs'.

Why doesn't it work? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<% include /layout/header.ejs %>` is evaluated in server side, hence it looks for absolute path in the disk, rather than a web url. When you make http request to `localhost:3000/layout/header.ejs`, the file is served.

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts to create various layouts and use it with different views.